# Как узнать расширение файла при его загрузке с сервера?

Tags: python, файлы, сервер, http, extension

В ссылке на скачивание файла не указано его расширение, однако браузеры при загрузке файла каким-то образом понимают, какой формат файла нужен. Как скрипт для загрузки файлов может узнать расширение подобного файла при его загрузке?

Comment: Никак. docx и всё остальное — это и есть самые настоящие zip-файлы

Comment: @andreymal а как тогда браузеры при загрузке файла понимают, какой формат файла нужен?

Comment: Тоже никак, информацию о формате высылает веб-сервер. Ну и сам веб-сервер обычно тоже никак не определяет формат, а просто смотрит расширение

Comment: Если прям совсем-совсем нужно как-то определять эти форматы, то нужно смотреть содержимое zip-архива и анализировать лежащие в них файлы. Я не знаю как это делать правильно, но утилита [file с библиотекой libmagic](https://github.com/file/file) умеют это делать, и возможно анализ их magic-файлов может помочь (ну или можно тупо запускать эту самую утилиту file и не париться с ручным парсингом сигнатур)

Comment: @andreymal тогда другой вопрос. Можно ли как-то посмотреть какое расширение передаёт сервер браузеру при загрузке файла?

Comment: Если в ссылке нет расширения, то возможно веб-сервер присылает его в HTTP-заголовке Content-Disposition, а также формат (MIME) в HTTP-заголовке Content-Type

Comment: @andreymal вот ссылка для примера: https://zakupki.gov.ru/44fz/filestore/public/1.0/download/priz/file.html?uid=BA68BBB1247BE4F6E0530F548D0A8FFB Как в данном конкретном случае браузер знает расширение файла?

Comment: @andreymal через Content-disposition?

Comment: Так и есть, [в Content-Disposition написано](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfIKF.png)

Comment: @andreymal вынесите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ в отдельный комментарий, чтобы я мог его отметить. Я изменю вопрос.

Comment: Есть другие заголовки, в зависимости от которых, pdf например открывается прямо в браузере (если браузер умеет его показывать), либо идёт на скачивание без попытки открыть в браузере, может это имеется ввиду? Для docx - такой поддержки нету.

Comment: По вашей ссылке - смотрите заголовок `Content-disposition`. Там по F12-сеть.

Comment: Попытавшись написать ответ, я внезапно осознал, что не знаю, как корректно декодировать Content-Disposition, а готовых и при этом корректных решений не нашлось :(